Connect ring terminal to PCB (low profile)
I have a BLDC motor control PCB (custom board - 15 A peak). The requirements for that board is to have low profile (max around 15-20 mm)
The chosen BLDC come with ring terminal crimp that need to be connected to "Mac8 M2 Screw Through Hole Tap" using a screw (please google the name and you'll get the full picture of the setup).
We faced sometimes a loose screws due to vibration of the motor.
The purpose of this post is to check other possible method to connect the ring terminal crimp to the PCB based on all the listed requirements.
If you don't have any potential idea I was thinking about using silicone, glue or solder to strengthen the connection and remove the vibration issues but I would like to have more idea about what kind of silicone I need to use or in case of repair, how I can dissolve it to access to the terminals?
Thank you.

Are you using some sort of spring washer now?

Do you need to use the "Mac8 M2 Screw Through Hole Tap"? Can you put a plated through hole in the board and use a bolt? The 14.7 N-cm (1.3 inch-pounds) torque for the TH-1.6-XX-M2 is practically nothing. A low strength thread locking compound will require more torque than that to release.

C. Dunn
Thank you for your comment, sorry as my background is mainly electronic and not mechanical but do you mean that the Mac8 M2 Screw Through Hole Tap cannot withstand high torque and it's more susceptible to be loosen? if i understand that correctly

Oof, 14.7N-cm on the TH-1.6-M 2 is almost nothing.
You can try adding lock or spring washers.
There are also chemical threadlockers you can evaluate, however when messy there may cause electrical issues. Buying screws with threadlocker pre-applied would be recommended.
Strain relief on the cables can also help, you could use RTV Sealant (eg: AS1701) to fixate the wires on the board.
